# Odd number returning two as prime factor

Tags: javascript, recursion, numbers

This function takes a number and returns its prime factors as an array. I ran a bunch of test cases and all comes out correct except this number `90000004000000001`.

The code is not optimized at all, so most numbers that large will time out. However, this one test case computes for some reason and it gives me the factors `[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 89, 241, 1049]` which is obviously nonsense since `90000004000000001` is an odd number.

When multiplying the factors together the resulting number is `90000004000000000`. `1` lower than the original number.

That's strange, so I tried `90000004000000001 % 2` which returns`0`.

I'm starting to think my function might not be the problem here but rather modulus or numbers in javascript. How come an even number can be divisible by 2 as in this case?

I put a few test cases as console logs together with the code snippet so you can see the results.

Thanks!

```js
// Assuming it works will factor an integer into its prime components and return them as an array
function factorize(num) {
  num = Math.floor(num);

  // the array to store all factors
  let factors = [];

  // goes through all numbers starting at 2
  // break when a factor is found
  // will also break if num is prime (its own factor)
  let i = 2;
  while (true) {
    if (num % i === 0) {
      factors.push(i);
      break;
    }
    i++
  }

  // i is the factor from the while loop
  // if num is not prime recursively factorize the remainder after factoring out i
  if (i !== num) {
    factors = factors.concat(factorize(num / i));
  }

  return factors;
}


console.log(factorize(16)); //[2, 2, 2, 2]
console.log(factorize(101)); //[101]
console.log(factorize(100001)); //[11, 9091]
console.log(factorize(141)); //[3, 47]
console.log(factorize(90000004000000001)); //[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 89, 241, 1049]
console.log(factorize(90000004000000001).reduce((a, b) => a * b)); //90000004000000000
```

Comment: I don't understand the negative sentiment on this site. The question is hardly a duplicate of the question it's supposedly a duplicate of. That question explains the issue, but it wasn't something that was obvious to look for as a new programmer. I provided test cases, code with good comments and clearly stated the issue. Why down vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your number is larger than the largest integer that can be exactly stored in a Javascript number value which is `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` with a value of 9007199254740991 , i.e. (2 ^ 53) - 1.

Expressed as a power of 2, your number is approximately equal to 2 ^ 56.32077 so it has 3.32 too many "bits" to be expressed accurately, meaning there'll be an error in the region of ±10 for any value in that range.

This is a limitation of the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) double precision floating point format.

It is therefore impossible to perform exact integer operations on it.

Just for fun, try this in your JS console:

```
> console.log(90000004000000001 + 1)
90000004000000000

> console.log(90000004000000001 + 9)
90000004000000020
```